# Drools checking for duplicate fields in a list

Tags: drools

I have an object A that contains a list of objects B that have various fields including a date field.  I need to write a rule that checks that dates are unique across the List but I'm a bit stuck in how to do this...I have something like:

```
rule "Check Unique Dates"
dialect "mvel"
when
    a : A
    list : java.util.List( ) from collect ( Date B.date (B.date!= null))
    set : java.util.Set( ) from collect ( Date B.date(B.date!= null))
    eval(list.size() == set.size())
then
    //do something
end
```

What I'm attempting to do is add the dates from object B to a list and also to a set and compare the sizes of the 2 but I get an error:

```
[ERR 102] Line 15:54 mismatched input 'B' in rule "Check Unique Dates" [0,0]: Parser returned a null Package
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I also need to limit it by a name field in A as there can be multiple instances of A...

Getting a bit closer I think...

```
when
    a : A

    b1 : B( d : date, date!= null )
    b2: B( date == d , eval( this != b1) )
```

but this does the check on all instances of B even if they are not in the list of this A instance (and the rules fires 1200 times even though there's only 6 B instances!?)...how do I limit the check to only look for duplicates in this A instance?

Comment: when
        a : A
        
        b1 : B( d : date, date!= null )
        b2: B( date == d , eval( this != b1) )
                                                                      but this does the check on all instances of B even if they are not in the list of this A instance...how do I limit the check?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I came up with..and it works:

```
when
    a : A( name == "xyz", coll : listOfB)       
    b1 : B( date1 : date, date!= null ) from coll
    b2 : B( date == date1, this != b1) from coll

then
```

now I need to go and lie down in a dark room...

Comment: Well you can always read this as: give me all collections from A where name == "xyz", then pick me two different items ( this != otherOne) and check against rules (date in your case). b1 and b2 without constraints are cartesian product of list elements, and your constraints are just helping to get two different ones from product.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to create a separate method for checking duplicates,
e.g. ListUtils.hasDuplicate(list)